# How do I make PKGBUILD to install to fake root before makepkg builds

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, pkgbuild, fakeroot, makepkg

I have a tree which I need to install with a foder named `/usr`. This folder exists in `src` folder. Now I need to write a function in `PKGBUILD` that installs to the fakeroot before the *.pkg.tar.gz is built. What needs to go in

> PKGBULD

```
package() {
    # I need to copy the 'usr' dir in 'srcdir' to PKGBUILD's fakeroot
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Creating_packages#package()) you should run something along the lines of `make DESTDIR="$pkgdir/" install` inside the `package()` function to install the files to the fakeroot directory. E.g.:

```
package() {
  cd "$srcdir/$pkgname-$pkgver"
  make DESTDIR="$pkgdir/" install
}
```

If you don't use make in your project, you can look at [what `make install` does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39895302/6058571) and adapt it to your needs.